# Pagination wordpress does not display

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have coded my theme from base and I have a problem displaying pagination in my page.
I have a `foreach` over my posts that is working properly and it is showing 9 posts in every page, but I could not display paginations below that to switch between page.
It would be great if someone can help me with it.

```
 <div class="row">
  <?php

  $args = array(

    'posts_per_page'   => 9,

    'offset'           => 0,

    'category'         => '',

    'category_name'    => '',

    'orderby'          => 'post_date',

    'order'            => 'DESC',

    'include'          => '',

    'exclude'          => '',

    'meta_key'         => '',

    'meta_value'       => '',

    'post_type'        => 'post',

    'post_mime_type'   => '',

    'post_parent'      => '',

    'post_status'      => 'publish',

    'suppress_filters' => true

  );

  $myposts = get_posts($args);

  foreach ($myposts as $post) : setup_postdata($post); ?>

    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12 mt-3">
      <div class="bg-gray h-100 blog-cards">
        <a href="<?php echo get_the_permalink();  ?>" title="more">
          <div>
            <div class="archive-img">
              <?= get_the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
            </div>

            <h3 class="upper mb-0 px-3 pt-3 pb-0 text-dark"> <?php echo get_the_title();    ?></h3>

            <div class="p-3 pt-0">
              <?php the_excerpt();  ?>
              <?php
              global $post;
              foreach (get_the_category($post->ID) as $category) {
                echo '<a href="' . get_category_link($category->term_id) . '">' . $category->name . '</a>';
              } ?> |
              <span>
                مدت زمان مطالعه
                <?= get_field('duration'); ?>
                دقیقه
              </span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    <?= previous_posts_link()?>      
</div>
```

It does not display with any of these built in functions

```
    <?= paginate_links() ?>
    <?= the_posts_pagination() ?>
    <?= get_the_posts_pagination() ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The functions you mention:

```
    <?= paginate_links() ?>
    <?= the_posts_pagination() ?>
    <?= get_the_posts_pagination() ?>
```

All require that the global `$wp_query` variable contains the necessary fields to generate the pagination (namely `found_posts`, `paged`, and `posts_per_page`).

Since you're using `get_posts`, the fields in `$wp_query` will never be set.

Instead, you can overwrite the `$wp_query` variable with a `WP_Query` instance which means the fields will be set. It is good practice to then restore `$wp_query` after your loop in case you have any data later in the page or in the footer that relies on it.

#### Example:

```php
global $wp_query;

$args = array(

    'posts_per_page'   => 9,
    // 'offset'           => 0,
    'orderby'          => 'post_date',
    'order'            => 'DESC',
    'post_type'        => 'post',
    'post_status'      => 'publish',
    // this one is important, it lets the query object know what page you're on.
    'paged'            => get_query_var( 'paged' ),
    // are you sure you want to suppress filters ? make sure you know what this does.
    'suppress_filters' => true,

);

$wp_query = new WP_Query( $args );
while ( $wp_query->have_posts() ) :
    $wp_query->the_post();
    ?>
 <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12 mt-3">
     <div class="bg-gray h-100 blog-cards">
         <a href="<?php echo get_the_permalink(); ?>" title="more">
             <div>
                 <div class="archive-img">
                     <?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
                 </div>

                 <h3 class="upper mb-0 px-3 pt-3 pb-0 text-dark"> <?php echo get_the_title(); ?></h3>

                 <div class="p-3 pt-0">
                     <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
                     <?php
                        global $post;
                        foreach ( get_the_category( get_the_ID() ) as $category ) {
                            echo '<a href="' . get_category_link( $category->term_id ) . '">' . $category->name . '</a>';
                        }
                        ?>
                      |
                     <span>
                         مدت زمان مطالعه
                         <?php echo get_field( 'duration' ); ?>
                         دقیقه
                     </span>
                 </div>
             </div>
         </a>
     </div>
 </div>
    <?php
endwhile;
the_posts_pagination();
// restore the original $wp_query.
wp_reset_postdata();
```